# How can I stop my div.content to overlap with my header?

Tags: html, css

```css
.myHeader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}    
h1 {
    font-size: 39px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.842);
    /* border-bottom: 2px solid #f6f4f84d; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 15px 18px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }


  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .content{
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="myHeader">
        <h1>The Foreign Journal</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
     something something
    </div>
</body>
```

I created a header with a class to fix my h1 and nav list at the top of my page. now every time I load any content in other body div they overlap with the first. Any suggestions?

I have tried to change the display from block to inline block but I am just stuck now, can't seems to solve it.

```
<body>
    <header class="myHeader">
        <h1>The Foreign Journal</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
     something something
    </div>

then on css 


.myHeader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}    
h1 {
    font-size: 39px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.842);
    /* border-bottom: 2px solid #f6f4f84d; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 15px 18px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }


  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .content{
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Set a fixed height for your header and add a "body" margin with the same value:

For example:

```
body {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.myHeader{
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
1. Remove "position" and "top" properties from ul selector.
2. Add "top" and "left" properties to ".myHeader" class.
3. Add a jQuery script to set the page's top margin dynamically.

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.myHeader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}  
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        let headerHeight = $('.myHeader').height();
        $('body').css({
            'margin-top': headerHeight + 'px'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Christoph! I used the solution one with css and it worked competely fine! Do you know what to do if I want then to add more div in my page, and then when scrolling down, don't get them to overlap ? do i need to use the sticky position of css?

Comment: No worries. You can prevent the background content from appearing in/on the header simply by setting the header's 'background-color' CSS property to, for instance, #fff. In case you'd like other divs, that are further down on the page, to kind of merge with the header, you can use 'position: sticky' with 'top: 200px' (from my example). Sticky divs will then get attached to the header as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

if you fix your header on the top of your page, it will overlap with your content that isn't fixed, you can avoid this by, for example, setting a top gap to your content.

I'll try to write a piece of code to show you.

In the following examples you'll see a div overlapping with the fixed header, and the second will stay below it, hope it helps !

Here you can see your body starting under the header, which is good if you want your header always fixed.

```css
body{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

header{
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  height: 100px;
}

.firstdiv{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.seconddiv{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Your header goes here</header>
  <div class="firstdiv">The rest of your website goes here</div>
  <div class="seconddiv">The rest of your website goes here</div>
</body>
```

You can see here that the second div will stay under your header if you position it 100px lower, that way you can have your content under your header.

```css
header{
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
}

.seconddiv{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Your header goes here</header>
  <div class="seconddiv">The rest of your website goes here</div>
</body>
```

This snippet shows your div overlapping the header when you dont move your content under the header

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  height: 100px;
}

.firstdiv{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Your header goes here</header>
  <div class="firstdiv">The rest of your website goes here</div>
</body>
```